# MySQL counting total number of zeros

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like

```
| id | day1 | day2 | day3 | day4 | day5 |
| 1  |  4   |  0   |  5   | 0    | 0    |
| 2  |  2   |  0   |  0   | 4    | 1    |
```

and I want to find to total number of zero entries for each id to give

```
| id | total_zeros |
| 1  | 3           |
| 2  | 2           |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT id, (day1=0)+(day2=0)+(day3=0)+(day4=0)+(day5=0) total_zeroes
FROM table
```

Comment: +1, and to make it even shorter one could use `!day1 + !day2 + ...`

Comment: @zerkms I thought of that. It's shorter, but I think this is clearer.

Comment: neither is ansi anyway :-)

Comment: My web site would be totally screwed if we had to migrate from mysql to a DBMS that only allowed ANSI syntax :)

Comment: hehe :-) In this case it's not that much about ansi to be that strong, but mysql to be that forgiving :-) I haven't worked with DBMS other than mysql that allowed to do so (postgresql, sql server, oracle)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
select 
id, if(day1=0,1,0)+if(day2=0,1,0)+ if(day3=0,1,0)+if(day4=0,1,0)+if(day5=0,1,0) as total
from test
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7ec5a/2)

Answer (score 1):

Why do people insist on making such un-usable tables?

You will have to use a case statement, and evaluate each column individually, and then add up the results.

Comment: But it doesn't violate normal forms (3rd one), does it?

Comment: Well, no, but it sure isn't very easy to query, at least in my opinion.  But I could be feeling grumpy today.

Comment: Any time you need have a repetitious columns like this, it's a strong sign that you should have used another table.

Comment: @Barmar: "that you should have used another table" - in that case there is a big chance that you will end up having endless transposes, because such kind of data is often used as it's presented in the original question.

Comment: Good point. You have to pick your poison, since mysql doesn't have a built-in pivot function.